# Comparing different methods for modeling Value at Risk (VaR) - understanding VaR backtesting results

Tags: p-value, quantiles, finance, model-comparison, risk

I estimated the Value at Risk of a time series of log returns with different approaches and models.
Now I want to compare the models and find the model that most accurately estimated the Value at Risk.

Therefore I use different VaR-backtesting approaches (e.g. the unconditional (Kupiec) or conditional (Christoffersen) coverage tests for the correct number of exceedances).

Per model, I get the test statistic and the $p$-palue of the UC and CC Test.
Assuming for all models, all test-statistics are small enough ($p$-value larger 0.05), so that I can not reject the Null Hypothesis, that the VaR estimate is correct.

My **assumption** is:

The higher the p-value the higher the likelihood of a good model. So I would prefer a model with a p-Value of 0.6 over a model with a p-Value of 0.4.

**Is that correct?**

I have related questions:

- [Evaluate Value at Risk (VaR) models with different VaR backtesting approaches - averaging p-values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622140/evaluate-value-at-risk-var-models-with-different-var-backtesting-approaches)
- [Choosing one method for modeling Value at Risk (VaR) over another - determining the "best" model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622136/choosing-one-method-for-modeling-value-at-risk-var-over-another-determining)

Answer (score 1):

I will address the question about the naive assumption (Question 2 in the updated post). I think the question is distinct enough to merit its own thread; you could probably split the other questions into a new thread, leaving this one more focused.

> My naive assumption would be: The higher the $p$-value the higher the likelihood of a good model.

I think your intuition is correct in the following sense. Under $H_0$, the $p$-value is distributed as $\text{Uniform}[0,1]$. Under $H_1$ we can have a variety of distributions depending on the relevant parameter values (the ones that do not conform to $H_0$) and the sample size. For larger samples, the distribution of the $p$-value under $H_1$ will concentrate closer to $0$ than $\text{Uniform}[0,1]$, making higher values unlikely. Therefore, if your sample size may be considered "large enough", a higher $p$-value is more likely a result of $H_0$ than of $H_1$.

Comment: Dear Richard, thanks a lot for your response and the good explanation.  Also, I agree, and I should probably split the other questions into a new thread. Nevertheless, do you have any opinion on these questions as well?

Comment: @Isabel, after you post the other two questions on separate threads, you can post links to them here, so then I can answer there (if I have an answer). Also, feel free to accept and/or upvote my answer if it is helpful.

Comment: I created another thread here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622136/choosing-one-method-for-modeling-value-at-risk-var-over-another-determining