# Choosing one method for modeling Value at Risk (VaR) over another - determining the "best" model

Tags: p-value, quantiles, finance, model-comparison, risk

I estimated the Value at Risk of a time series of log returns with different approaches and models. Now I want to compare the models and chose the model that most accurately estimated the Value at Risk.

**Question:**

- How can I determine which model is best? Which model should I choose?

My current approaches are:

- Example plots and
- VaR backtesting approaches (e.g. the unconditional (Kupiec) or conditional (Christoffersen) coverage tests for the correct number of exceedances).

But I don't know how to choose one model over another, e. g. the VaR backtesting for all methods suggests that I can not reject the Null Hypothesis.

Thanks!

I have related questions:

- [Evaluate Value at Risk (VaR) models with different VaR backtesting approaches - averaging p-values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622140/evaluate-value-at-risk-var-models-with-different-var-backtesting-approaches)
- [Comparing different methods for modeling Value at Risk (VaR) - understanding VaR backtesting results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621342/comparing-different-methods-for-modeling-value-at-risk-var-understanding-var)

Comment: In my opinion, there are two distinct questions here (model selection and averaging of $p$-values), so the focus would be better if they were split into separate threads.

Comment: There you go (; https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622140/evaluate-value-at-risk-var-models-with-different-var-backtesting-approaches

Comment: Thanks, Isabel!