# Evaluate Value at Risk (VaR) models with different VaR backtesting approaches - averaging p-values?

Tags: p-value, quantiles, finance, model-comparison, risk

I estimated the Value at Risk of a time series of log returns with different approaches and models. Now I want to compare the models and choose the model that most accurately estimated the Value at Risk on the basis of multiple VaR backtesting approaches (e.g. the unconditional (Kupiec) or conditional (Christoffersen) coverage tests for the correct number of exceedances).

Per model, I get the test statistic and the two p-values of the tests (UC and CC test). Assuming for all models, all test-statistics are small enough (p-value larger 0.05), so that I can not reject the Null Hypothesis, that the VaR estimate is correct.

**Question:**

How to chose one model over another on the basis of different tests / p-values? Can I calculate the mean p-value over all tests and choose the model with the highest mean p-value?

I have related questions:

- [Choosing one method for modeling Value at Risk (VaR) over another - determining the "best" model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622136/choosing-one-method-for-modeling-value-at-risk-var-over-another-determining)
- [Comparing different methods for modeling Value at Risk (VaR) - understanding VaR backtesting results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621342/comparing-different-methods-for-modeling-value-at-risk-var-understanding-var)